# Javascript calling function inside function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the function in a function with argument inside the child function

```
function firstF (){
  this.childF1 = function($argument){
    // do something + $argument
  }
  this.childF2 = function($argument2){
    // do something + $argument2
  }
}

//Declare a new firstF
var firstFunction = new firstF();
firstFunction.childF1
```

how do i declare the $argument here?

Comment: `firstF.childF1("arg");`

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
var firstFunction = new firstF();
firstFunction.childF1(arghere)
```

`childF1` is a property of your `firstF` object and that property is a function.  So, you call it like a function with parens and you pass the arguments in the parens.  You must call it on an already created object of type `firstF`, not on the `firstF` function itself.